# Servlet request contenttype = null when submitting multipart/form-data

Tags: java, html, forms, servlets, file-upload

I'm trying to create a servlet-based form that allows a user to submit several files to a backend server.

The form consists of several file selectors.

The form is sent from one servlet printing it to the output stream as text/html. (A lot of the page is dependant on wether the user is logged in etc.)

In the browser the html looks like this:

```
 <form action="https://localhost:8441/uploadtest" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

When i select one or more files and click the submit button the request is forwarded to the right link however my file upload handler can't process the data as the request.getContentType() is null.

I use an embedded jetty 9 server to host the servlets. The servlet api version is 3.0. The handler throws an exception indicating the content type is null which is also confirmed by the output of the print statement I added for debugging.

I have been searching & looking for problems for a few hours now and I can't figure out why the content type is set to null even though the form submits a POST request with enctype as multipart/form-data.

The handler code is this:

```
    @Override
public void doHandle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String contentType = request.getContentType();
    System.out.println(contentType);
    if (contentType != null && contentType.startsWith("multipart/form-data")) {
        baseRequest.setAttribute(Request.__MULTIPART_CONFIG_ELEMENT, MULTI_PART_CONFIG);
    }
            //processing here.
```

Comment: Are you using servlets 3.0 or prior like 2.5?

Comment: Servlet api 3.0, as included with this jetty version.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Using firebug I managed to verify that the HTML part sent the form correctly. After stripping the entire application down to nothing it turned out that the request was being lost some time after arrival at the Jetty 9 server before landing at the handler dealing with it.

I managed to "fix" it by mapping the handler to the "/" path as the very first handler on the server. When parsing requests it checks if the destination path is "/files" and if it's multipart/form-data. If so it handles it, if not it ignores the request.

At this point jetty default handling will forward the non-form requests to the rest of the handlers on the server properly.

It's a bit hacky and if anyone can tell me why mapping the file handler to the "/files" (or any) URL causes the request to be lost it'd be great but for now at least I got it working.

In case anyone is having the same problem, here is the code for the relevant bit in the server configuration:

```
    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    server.setHandler(contexts);
    new FileUploadHandler(contexts,"/");
    ServletContextHandler root = new ServletContextHandler(contexts,"/");
            //more servlets & handlers here.
```

and the handler itself:

```
 HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (!request.getPathInfo().equals("/files")) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(request.getContentLength());
    if (request.getContentType() != null && request.getContentType().startsWith("multipart/form-data")) {
        baseRequest.setAttribute(Request.__MULTIPART_CONFIG_ELEMENT, MULTI_PART_CONFIG);
    } else {    
        response.sendRedirect(URL.INDEX.getURL());
    }
              //more processing here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void doHandle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {}
```

here you used `doHandle` were as in form you used `method="post"`

Comment: The issue is with the post request received from the webpage. Not with the response from the servlet. Thank you for taking the time to try and help though.

Comment: ok if your ques has been resolved you can paste your ans here...for further usage..thankyou

Comment: It has not, I meant that the issue is with the getContentType() of the request, not the response.

Comment: Could you please leave at least a note when you completely change your answer? I did not notice you rewrote it untill just now. I will clarify the problem in the main post to answer this.